# How to fake throwing an exception?

Tags: fakeiteasy

I have following setup

```
A.CallTo(() => fakeChargeService
       .CreateAsync(A<ChargeCreateOptions>._, A<RequestOptions>._, A<CancellationToken>._))
 .Throws<StripeException>((se) => stripeException);
```

and then I assert

```
 var msg = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<StripeException>(async () => await mediator.Send(command, CancellationToken.None));
```

which eventually executes this piece of code

```
        var policyResult = await Policy.Handle<StripeException>(x => x.ShouldRetry())
                                       .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
                                       {
                                           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5),
                                           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                                           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                                       })
                                       .ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async () => await this.chargeService.CreateAsync(options, null, cancellationToken));
```

and here I get error

**Assert.Throws() Failure
Expected: typeof(Stripe.StripeException)
Actual:   typeof(FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationException): The faked method has the signature (Stripe.ChargeCreateOptions, Stripe.RequestOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken), but throws was used with (Stripe.StripeException).**

I am not sure what is it that  I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be specifying the wrong signature in your `Throws`. `CreateAsync` takes `(Stripe.ChargeCreateOptions, Stripe.RequestOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken)`, but `Throws` was used with `(Stripe.StripeException)`.

See the second example in [Throwing Exceptions](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/throwing-exceptions/):

```
// Pass up to 4 original call argument values into the method that creates the exception.
A.CallTo(() => fakeShop.NumberOfSweetsSoldOn(A<DateTime>._))
 .Throws((DateTime when)=>new InvalidDateException(when + " is in the future"));
```

Note that the signature of the lambda and the called method match.

You should update your lambda to match the proper signature. Or better yet, just replace with

```
.Throws<StripeException>(stripeException)
```

since there doesn't appear to be any reason to lazily throw, based on the snippet of code you provided.